# How to show/fetch amount of posts, comments etc a user has made

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show the users the amount of posts, comments etc they have created in their profile section, just like any other forums that exist. I am doing this with php and MYSQLI. Post table:

```
1   post_id Primary int(11)     AUTO_INCREMENT  

    2   title   varchar(255)

    3   users_id    int(11)     

    4   content   varchar(500)      
    5   type    int(11)                     
    6   imagepath   varchar(50) 
    7   date_created    datetime
```

I have tried to add another column to the post table and increment its value by 1 each time the user makes a post in php by an INSERT statement but it's value only stays at 1, even though the user continues to create more posts. Here is what I tried:

```
function createPost($conn, $content, $title, $users_id, $date_created, $type, $total_post){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, users_id, content, date_created, type, total_post) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
     header("location: ../home.php?error=stmtfailed");
     exit();
    }

    $mysqltime = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $total_post++;
    $type;


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $title, $users_id, $content, $mysqltime, $type, $total_post);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../home.php?error=noerroronpost");
     exit();
 }
```

This is in profile.php where im trying to display the information to the user

```
      $id = $_SESSION["userid"];
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * from post LEFT JOIN users on users.users_id = ? order by post_id DESC;');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<div class='userinfo'>";
        echo "<h5 id='usernameprofile'>" ."Username: " .$row["users_username"] ."</h5>";
        echo "<h5 id='usernameprofile'>" ."Registration date: " .$row["create_datetime"] ."</h5>";
        echo "<h5 id='usernameprofile'>" ."Posts: " .$row["post_id"] ."</h5>"; echo "<br>";
        echo "</div>";
        }

        $stmt->close();
```

EDITED: Thanks to ADyson the query he provided worked perfectly. I tweaked it a bit to just show the amount of posts.

```
        $id = $_SESSION["userid"];   
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(p.post_id) as total_posts from post p INNER JOIN users ON users.users_id = p.users_id WHERE p.users_id = ?;');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $count = $row['total_posts'];

        echo "<div class='usertotalpost'>";
        echo "<h5 id='totalposts'>" ."Posts: " .$count ."</h5>"; echo "<br>";
        echo "</div>";
        }

        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: You don't need an extra column or table or anything. Just use a SELECT COUNT... query whenever you want to know the number of posts. Likewise for scores you would probably use SUM to calculate that. You don't need to store such values because SQL can just calculate them for you in real-time when they're needed.

Comment: @ADyson I see, however the primary key post_id is auto_incremented and only shows the amount of total posts from all time, and not for the specific user. How would I be able to do so in a SELECT COUNT query?

Comment: you can do so because COUNT counts the number of actual rows in the table at the time it executes - it doesn't rely on ID values or anything else (as an aside, the purpose of the primary key field is to permanently uniquely identify a specific row, not to count how many rows there are... the fact it's a numeric value is purely incidental, e.g. a GUID would work just as well). And you can filter (using WHERE) and/or GROUP the data to get totals for a specific user or users.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on COUNT and GROUP BY if you're unfamiliar with the concept. Try it out, and then apply the knowledge to your own scenario: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php, and then https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php

Comment: Here's another: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-using-group-by-to-count-the-number-of-rows-for-each-unique-entry-in-a-column/ . There are dozens of such tutorials online.

Comment: @ADyson However I am a bit confused as I still need to join user and post tables together, while trying to fetch the amount of posts a user has made.  SELECT * from post LEFT JOIN users on users.users_id = ? order by post_id DESC; This statement does provide me with the users name and the registration date but the total amount of posts is 280 because its the ALL TIME posts. I edited the question to provide more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll still need to count and group if you want to see totals per user. And your join style is all wrong too - you're supposed to link columns in each table together to make the join, not just restrict on an input field.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT
  u.users_username, 
  u.create_datetime, 
  COUNT(p.post_id) AS total_posts
FROM 
  post p
  INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.users_id = p.users_id
WHERE 
  p.users_id = ?
GROUP BY 
  u.users_username, 
  u.create_datetime
```

(Obviously the WHERE clause is optional - if you want to a see a list of totals for all users then remove it.)

Comment: This seems very clean, should I still be using $id = $_SESSION["userid"]? I'm getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool, it is the session variable for the users_id in usertable and not for the one in post table

Comment: `should I still be using $id = $_SESSION["userid"]? `...if you want to restrict by a specific user, then yes. You'd bind it to the `?` I showed in the query, same as you're doing in your existing example.

Comment: `it is the session variable for the users_id in usertable and not for the one in post table`...if the IDs are the same for the rows which are related, then your comment doesn't matter - they're both identical numbers, so it would match either of them! (Which is also why the JOIN would work)

Comment: `Call to a member function bind_param() on bool`...so have you googled that? It's very common. Basically it means the prepare() failed (and returned `false` (a bool!) as per its documentated behaviour. However, that means you're not handling mysqli errors in the recommended modern way. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically...

Comment: ....Once we see the specific SQL error message then we'll be able to work out how to fix it. Probably I made some minor syntax error or field name error - I wrote the query without being able to test it, obviously, and I only have limited information about your database schema.

Comment: amazing, i will use that mysqli report forever now, some of the columns were not named properly so i changed and it worked. However, where I am trying to show the output * $row["post_id"] * it says post_id array key is undefined

Comment: Well yes, obviously...look at the query I wrote and see what column names it outputs. Then adjust your PHP code accordingly.

Comment: I can't thank you enough sir, it worked. I'm going to play around with this for other stuff I need to add as well. Big thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. If you want to edit the answer with the changes you needed to make to the query, and then mark it as accepted, that would be helpful for future readers too.

Comment: Actually I mean you should edit my _answer_ .... the solution does not form part of your question :-)

Comment: But if you aren't going to select anything except the COUNT field, or otherwise make use of the `users` table, then you don't need the JOIN, just write `SELECT COUNT(p.post_id) as total_posts from post p WHERE p.users_id = ?`

Comment: Oh okay I see, didnt know I could edit your answer. The thing that occurred is that if the user hasnt posted anything then the query and the results will not be shown? I was hoping it would atleast say total posts = 0 but no it wont, and I will bring back the users name and date just for the sake of it haha

Comment: @Hamodicoolguy it should still show 0 if the user hasn't posted anything - demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd87cce36f36fe483d8d79eab837bf10

Comment: interesting, how would I go about with the query if lets say I want to output the total posts, total reviews, total comments etc determined by the *type* column? Right now I have if type is == 0 it is a regular post, if type == 1 then it's a review and so on.

Comment: sounds like you'd group it by the Type, and then output all the resulting rows.

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c097d39688406e4ee3636f9a0dafebe

Comment: so nothing like if($row['type'] == 0)?

Comment: Why bother? Sql can do it more easily, as I've shown